# How do I apply a projection to a Spring Data REST query method resource?

Tags: java, spring, rest, projection, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Data REST 2.1.4.RELEASE.

I created

- an entity `Booking`,
- its REST repository (extending `CrudRepository`) named `BookingRepository`
- and a **projection** `BookingDetails` (annotated with `@Projection(name="details", types = Booking.class)`) for returning some of its linked entities exploded, such as `Resource`, `Activity`, `Applicant` etc.

The client gets all bookings with `.../rest/bookings` and the JSON response includes links for the linked entities. If it adds `?projection=details` then the linked entities are exploded and returned. And this is great.

Now I add this **custom method** to the repository:

```
List<Booking> findByApplicant(@Param("applicant") Person applicant);
```

When the client invokes it with `.../rest/bookings/search/findByApplicant?applicant=5`, there seem to be no way to request the `details` projection. Following attempts are ignored:

- adding `&projection=details` to the query string
- making the method always return `BookingDetails`:

  ```
  List<BookingDetails> findByApplicant(@Param("applicant") Person applicant);
  ```

Summarizing, **custom search methods (`findBy*`) never return a projection**. Unless you annotate the repository with `@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = BookingDetails.class)`, but this leads to some problems, first of all the client has to always use the same projection. How can we allow the user to use projections also with `findBy*` methods?

Comment: An URL like `.../rest/bookings/search/findByApplicant?applicant=5` is not very RESTful. What about `.../rest/bookings?applicant=5`?

Comment: While it's totally unrelated to the original posters question, what's unrestful about this URI? To be precise, you can't judge restfulness of a URI by definition as it solely depends on whether the resource exposed through it follows HTTP semantics. Whether the id of the resource is `/foo` or `/conquer/the/world` is completely irrelevant.

That said, Spring Data REST leverages hypermedia to let clients navigate to the resources so the structure if the ids of the resources even becomes less that not relevant at all :).

Comment: The URL smells like RPC. Of course hypermedia is a Good Thing.

Comment: URIs don't smell, they're an opaque thing. It's the resources that matter and how they behave :).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I verfied this working with Spring Data REST 2.2.1, so please update it. Make sure your client actually sends the the requested parameters as you intend. While debugging, I found out that e.g. cURL drops query parameters if you do not explicitly quote the URI. So this:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/orders/search/findByApplicant?applicant=5&projection=details
```

will *not* send any of the query parameters. Once you quote the URI, it will.

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/orders/search/findByApplicant?applicant=5&projection=details'
```

Sort of the same is in place for the increasingly popular [HTTPie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie#request-items). With it the required syntax is:

```
http :8080/orders/search/findByApplicant applicant==5 projection==details
```

In case you can't get it to work that way, it would be cool to get a running example project to look at.

Comment: thank you a lot! I fill stupid: I tested this with Spring Data REST 2.1.4 some days ago and didn't work; then I updated to 2.2.1 and didn't test (I only tested the new `excerptProjection`). Now that I test.. I see that it works!! I didn't thought this could be implemented just now that I need it :D Now I correct my question. Thanks and sorry for the waste of time!

Comment: Don't worry. I felt kind of stupid, too, seeing no parameters at all with a plain, unquoted `cURL`. Plus, it's still good to get these questions as they become a canonical reference for others running into the same issue :). Glad it works for you!

Comment: Hi, I ran into similar situation. The above solution works for custom query methods. But how do add a projection for inbuilt methods. for example, If I have a Order entity, /orders will give me all the orders with projection applied. But when I search for individual order using the self.href link for example  /orders/58fa7da00498e41f81a9f806, the projection is not applied. How can I achieve that?