# Can projections be applied to associations in Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring, spring-data, projection, spring-data-rest

We can apply projections to [search resources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28362756/18027) and usual list resources. This question is about associations.

Suppose we have resource `Business` and it has one-to-many relationship with `Client` through an association named `clients`

When exported through spring-data-rest we can access an individual `Business` resource with URL like following:

http://localhost/businesses/1

and the association resource as

http://localhost/businesses/1/clients

The question is, can we apply a projection to client objects returned from the second url, like `http://localhost/businesses/1/clients?projection=withAddress` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it on a one-to-many association and it works. Simply using `?projection=XYZ` is enough.

It was not obvious as generated HAL links for association resources does not contain the projection parameter template like other links.